# Filter html response from urllib with re.sub

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

What i am trying to is to get the html response of a website as a variable string and filter out everything except dots(.), numbers(0-9), colons(:). I can't seem to get this right with re.sub. Is it possible ?

```
import urllib.request
import re

ans = True

while ans:
    print("""
      - Menu Selection -
      1. Automatic 
      2. Automatic w/Checker
      3. Manual
      4. Add to list
      5. Exit
      """)
ans = input('Select Option : ')

 if ans =="1":
    try :
        with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.mywebsite.net') as response: 
           html = response.read()
           html = str(html)
           html = re.sub(r'([a-z][A-Z])', '', html)
           f = open('text.txt','a')
           f.write(html)
           f.close()
           print('Data(1) saved.')
           ans = True
    except :
            print('Error on first fetch.')
```

This outputs the whole html code and does not filter out any of the characters. 
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: please consider pasting code to be able to run your program, have you attempted anything to filter out the characters?

Comment: Entered the whole of the code. I have attempted with html = re.sub(r'([a-z][A-Z])', '', html) but this still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to exclude the three things you mentioned and make the pattern as follows - here html is your input string

```
re.sub('[^0-9\.:]', '', html)
```

Comment: Not enough reputation yet :| . I' ll do it as soon as i get there.

Answer (score 1):

We want `html = re.sub('[0-9.:]', '', html)`. Strings are immutable in Python so the only way to modify the string is to construct a new string: so all string functions returns new string instead of modifying them in-place (which is impossible in Python). This new string have to be assigned to some variable or it will be lost forever (as in your example).

Comment: Thank you for the correction. But i still can't get the re.sub function to work as intended.

Comment: I missed an error in your regex, as mentioned by @minocha in the other answer.